# How to pass path (namespace) and params to CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost

Tags: ios, websocket

I'm trying to connect to web socket server using the **CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost** method

When my server is set without any paths or params i'm getting **NSStreamEventOpenCompleted**

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef) @"demo.example.com, 345, &readStream, &writeStream);

outputStream = (__bridge NSOutputStream *)writeStream;
inputStream = (__bridge NSInputStream *)readStream;

[outputStream setDelegate:self];
[inputStream setDelegate:self];

[outputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];
[inputStream scheduleInRunLoop:[NSRunLoop currentRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode];

[outputStream open];
[inputStream open];

- (void)stream:(NSStream *)theStream handleEvent:(NSStreamEvent)streamEvent {
// streamEvent == NSStreamEventOpenCompleted
...
}
```

The problem starts when i set the server with path and params.
For example, I need to connect to: *https://demo.example.com:345/some/path?key=val&key2=val2*

I tried to pass the paths and the params to the host as follows:

```
CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost(kCFAllocatorDefault, (__bridge CFStringRef) @"demo.example.com/some/path?key=val&key2=val2", 345, &readStream, &writeStream);
```

It did not succeed leading to a **kCFHostErrorHostNotFound** response

How can i pass path (namespace) and params to CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost correctly?